# How to specify a significance test for intercept and slope between multiple latent groups

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, latent-class, growth-model, mplus

I have done a Latent Profile Analysis on 34 symptom-distress-items at beginning of psychotherapy treatment. I came up with 5 latent groups. The entropy of the model was 0.779

The average Latent Class Probabilities for Most Likely Latent Class Membership (Row) by Latent Class (Column) was:

```
       1        2        3        4        5

1   0.933    0.015    0.026    0.026    0.000
2   0.005    0.836    0.037    0.117    0.005
3   0.020    0.048    0.897    0.035    0.000
4   0.008    0.079    0.019    0.874    0.019
5   0.000    0.012    0.000    0.037    0.951
```

I have also measured treatment progress every session.

I would like to use the grouping variable from the LPA in a growth model to investigate if the 5 latent groups differ in distress at intake (intercept) and rate of improvement (slope).

I used R to calculate this using a mixed model and a contrast matrix but I did not consider the measurement insecurity of the latent groups. I figure that since the error was between 0.84-0.95 the results I got would hold anyway. My question is : If this assumption is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "on another measure?"

Comment: debugging questions are off-topic here and should be asked on Stack Overflow instead

Comment: I think this is a general stat question which is on-topic here. I've edited the question to make it more general and not specific to Mplus. I think the answer is "likelihood ratio test" as well, but I'm waiting for clarification from OP as to exactly what they're asking.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @CJ_U, I don't understand the question any more.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Did you get pinged? Really sorry - wonder why that happens - I'd assumed the only person who'd get a ping was the OP. (If you check the edit history you'll see the OP was confused why they couldn't edit their own question, but it was due to an account problem.)

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Why dont you merge the two models into one model so that you use the latent class to predict the mean and slope [varI on C] or let them vary between the latent groups